# Access to path is denied Visual C# 2013

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, opennlp

I am using Apache OpenNLP in .Net project and I am trying to access a bin file in my project directory.
but the same error keep showing up no matter what I do:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Users\esev\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SuperChat\SuperChat\SuperChat.Windows\Assets\en-token.bin' is denied.
```

I am running the program as administrator and my SYSTEM, User(esev) and administrators has full control and permission to write an read files:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp1ud.png

Here is the Code:

```
public String[] tokenization(String tokens) {

        InputStream iss;
        TokenizerModel tm;

        try {
            iss = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/esev/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/SuperChat/SuperChat/SuperChat.Windows/Assets/en-token.bin");
            tm = new TokenizerModel(iss);
            TokenizerME tz = new TokenizerME(tm);
            String[] Tokens = tz.tokenize(tokens);
            return Tokens;

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

I am using this method as a part of a java class, is this connected somehow to my problem?
What is the solution?

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: Is it System.UnauthorizedAccessException ? If it is, then Sometimes when you Combine the path with File Name It is considered as Path Directory not a file. Try using `Path.Combine()`

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you talk about a VS project and tag as C#, but then you show Java code? Can you please clarify? If the code you show is causing the error then how is this related to C# / Visual Studio?

Comment: Review the properties of the file en-token.bin, and be sure that the administrator have a permission read on it. Your screen shoot is for vs and it is totaly different for file access permission

Comment: Is `en-token` a file or a folder? It needs to be a file or you may get this error. If it's definitely a file, then try copying it into a directory off the root of C:, like C:\foobar. Then try accessing it from there. If you can, then it's a simple read-write or permissions issue.

Comment: ok to clarify: I am  running visual studio as administrator, It is a FileNotFoundExecption, I used ikvm to combine my jar files into a dll so I am using java methods inside a C# class, I checked and the bin file is permitted to read from all users, and en-token is a bin file not a folder

Comment: Your exception already tells you what's wrong. The file-path you gave to the method does not point to a valid file. try debugging your input to see what exactly you try to open and what you did wrong.

Comment: the thing is that I made the exact same method in a java class in eclipse and it works perfectly, but in .Net does not accept the path. I also tried to change the path to a jpg file in the same directory(which is a valid file) but I encountered the same problem, so that means that the file is not the problem